# Draw image xcode6 ios8

Tags: ios, xcode6

Good afternoon,

I would like to know if I can take a picture and then draw something in the image (with the finger movement, for example, a black line "handwritted"). Is it possible?

If that's possible... How can I start doing that?

**Edit:**

I want to take a picture from my iPhone (that's what I currently have in my App) and then I would like to draw something in that picture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But this is far too broad a question to reasonably answer on a Q&A forum.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I just need something to start... A tutorial a Framework... Just something because I don't even have the idea that this could be done. Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure you'll find a single tutorial. You'll need to know about images. About detecting touches. About drawing shapes. It's not a two minute job.

Comment: I know that this is not going to be easy Stephen, but I would like to know how can I do that. I have to use some Framework? Some API?

Comment: As I said above, this is far too broad a question to answer. You need to look at UIKit, which is iOS's user interface framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one tutorial to this. And as @Stephen mentioned in the comments, it is not a 2 min job. However, you can start with the following tutorials.

1. http://w3z.in/7ef - How To Make A Simple Drawing App with UIKit.
2. http://w3z.in/9b1 - Apple's official UIKit guide.
3. http://w3z.in/e2c - iOS 7 graphics tutorial.

The key here would be to have patience, do some small experiment apps and then figure out what to do in your app.

Thanks

Comment: If you feel satisfied. You can mark the answer as complete.